# llvm undefined experimental intrinsics

Tags: c, llvm

I am trying to edit the llvm ir code:

```
define { double, double } @add(double, double, double, double) local_unnamed_addr #0 {
  %5 = call double @llvm.experimental.constrained.fadd(double %0, double %2, metadata !"round.downward", metadata !"fpexcept.ignore")
  %6 = fadd double %1, %3
  %7 = insertvalue { double, double } undef, double %5, 0
  %8 = insertvalue { double, double } %7, double %6, 1
  ret { double, double } %8
}
```

where on line 2 using an experimental intrinsic from llvm, the document can be found [here](https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#constrained-floating-point-intrinsics)

When compiling the llvm code using llvm-as, I get the error:

```
use of undefined value '@llvm.experimental.constrained.fadd'
```

The code I use to compile it to binary is:

```sh
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/llvm-as interval.ll -o interval.bc
```

Is there any special flags I need to add in order to use the experimental intrinsics?

Answer (score 0):

Change`@llvm.experimental.constrained.fadd` to `@llvm.experimental.constrained.fadd.f64` and add the declare `declare double @llvm.experimental.constrained.fadd.f64(double, double, metadata, metadata)`

Comment: Hi, so I found the problem later on which is actually not declaring the functions in the file.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, with every function used in llvm, you need to declare it somewhere in the file.